# Tag styling on superuser

Tags: discussion, style

The tags on superuser has a 3-4 px thick blue border. Because of this, I find lists of questions a bit hard to read compared to stackoverflow.com. The border takes the focus away from the titles, enough to be a little annoying.

What about giving them a thinner border, a lighter colored border, or removing the border altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I kind of wish the tags (on all the sites) didn't have a border or background colour. Sure, they'd look similar to the "link|flag" text at the bottom of each post, but they're just metadata and shouldn't be so obtrusive. Reducing the border width is a good start.

SF's "tooltip" coloured tags are the best across all the sites IMHO.

Comment: I like SF's tags too, but I dislike SF's number of answers box on the question list page the most.

Comment: Agreed - the dotted borders are very distracting. The solid boxes of SO and MSO are the nicest looking.

Answer (score 0):

Aye I agree. A change in contrast like that tells your eyes that there are objects there needing to focus on. Instead being a more softer contrast between white and grey (like here on MSO)

Specially with it having rounded corners, telling your eyes that it's a complex object.